# Developing an Algorithm to Transform Four Cartesian Coordinates Into Square Coordinates

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science

I am working on a project where four randomly placed robots each have unique Cartesian coordinates. I need to find a way to transform these coordinates into the coordinates of a square with side length defined by the user of the program.

For example, let's say I have four coordinates (5,13), (8,17), (13,2), and (6,24) that represent the coordinates of four robots. I need to find a square's coordinates such that the four robots are closest to these coordinates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to find the four points such that those four points form a square, and the total distance from each robot to the nearest square point is minimized? (Or perhaps, the four points such that if each point is assigned to one robot, the total distance from each point to each robot is minimized)?

Comment: Can you add the expected result for the example in your question?

Comment: What is a "square's coordinates"? That is not a standard term. A square has four corners but three degrees of freedom. What are you trying to measure as being close to the robot coordinates?

Comment: I am trying to find four points that form a square and if each point is assigned to one robot, the total distance from each point to each robot is minimized.

Comment: it is okay, I figured it out myself. thank you for everyone's help

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, otherwise this question is of no use to anybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you are looking for the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the four points, the point which has equal — and thus minimal — distance to all points. It is calculated as the average for each coordinate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The square's edge length is irrelevant to the position, though.

**Update**

If you additionally want to minimize the square corners' distance to a robot position, you can do the following:

1. Calculate the centroid *c* like described above and place the square there.
2. Imagine a circle with center at *c* and diameter of the square's edge length.
3. For each robot position calculate the point on the circle with shortest distance to the robot and use that as a corner of the square.

Comment: What would I do if the arrangement of the robots is such that the polygon created by connecting their coordinates is concave, and not convex. I wouldn't be able to find the centroid, so then what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the original poster is not coming back to share his solution here, so I'll post what I was working on.

Finding the center point of the four robots and then drawing the square around this point is indeed a good way to start, but it doesn't necessarily give the optimal result. For the example given in the question, the center point is (8,14) and the total distance is 22.688 (assuming a square size of 10).

[image: square in center position with vectors]

When you draw the vector from a corner of the square to the closest robot, this vector shows you in which direction the square should move to reduce the distance from that corner to its closest robot. If you calculate the sum of the direction of these four vectors (by changing the vectors to size 1 before adding them up) then moving the square in the resulting direction will reduce the total distance.

[image: the four vectors and the resulting direction]

I dreaded venturing into differential equation territory here, so I devised a simple algorithm which repeatedly calculates the direction to move in, and moves the square in ever decreasing steps, until a certain precision is reached.
For the example in the question, the optimal location it finds is (10,18), and the total distance is 21.814, which is an improvement of 0.874 over the center position (assuming a square size of 10).

[image: the optimal position]

Press "run code snippet" to see the algorithm in action with randomly generated positions. The scattered green dots are the center points that are considered while searching the optimal location for the square.

```js
function positionSquare(points, size) {

    var center = {x: 0, y:0};
    for (var i in points) {
        center.x += points[i].x / points.length;
        center.y += points[i].y / points.length;
    }

    paintSquare(canvas, square(center), 1, "#D0D0D0");
    order(points);
    textOutput("<P>center position: " + center.x.toFixed(3) + "," + center.y.toFixed(3) + "<BR>total distance: " + distance(center, points).toFixed(3) + "</P>");

    for (var step = 1; step > 0.0001; step /= 2)
    {
        var point = center;
        var shortest, dist = distance(center, points);

        do
        {
            center = point;
            shortest = dist;
            var dir = direction();
            paintDot(canvas, center.x, center.y, 1, "green");
            point.x = center.x + Math.cos(dir) * step;
            point.y = center.y + Math.sin(dir) * step;
            dist = distance(point, points);
        }
        while (dist < shortest)
    }
    textOutput("<P>optimal position: " + center.x.toFixed(3) + "," + center.y.toFixed(3) + "<BR>total distance: " + distance(point, points).toFixed(3) + "</P>");
    return square(center);

    function order(points) {
        var clone = [], best = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            clone[i] = points.slice();
            for (var j in clone[i]) clone[i][j].n = j;

            if (i) {
                clone[i].sort(function(a, b) {return b.y - a.y});
                if (clone[i][0].x > clone[i][1].x) swap(clone[i], 0, 1);
                if (clone[i][2].x < clone[i][3].x) swap(clone[i], 2, 3);
            } else {
                clone[i].sort(function(a, b) {return a.x - b.x});
                swap(clone[i], 1, 3);
                if (clone[i][0].y < clone[i][3].y) swap(clone[i], 0, 3);
                if (clone[i][1].y < clone[i][2].y) swap(clone[i], 1, 2);
            }
        }
        if (distance(center, clone[0]) > distance(center, clone[1])) best = 1;
        for (var i in points) points[i] = {x: clone[best][i].x, y: clone[best][i].y};

        function swap(a, i, j) {
            var temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    function direction() {
        var d, dx = 0, dy = 0, corners = square(center);
        for (var i in points) {
            d = Math.atan2(points[i].y - corners[i].y, points[i].x - corners[i].x);
            dx += Math.cos(d);
            dy += Math.sin(d);
        }
        return Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    }

    function distance(center, points) {
        var d = 0, corners = square(center);
        for (var i in points) {
            var dx = points[i].x - corners[i].x;
            var dy = points[i].y - corners[i].y;
            d += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
        }
        return d;
    }

    function square(center) {
        return [{x: center.x - size / 2, y: center.y + size / 2},
                {x: center.x + size / 2, y: center.y + size / 2},
                {x: center.x + size / 2, y: center.y - size / 2},
                {x: center.x - size / 2, y: center.y - size / 2}];
    }
}

// PREPARE CANVAS
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 200; canvas.height = 200;
canvas = canvas.getContext("2d");

// GENERATE TEST DATA AND RUN FUNCTION
var points = [{x:5, y:13}, {x:8, y:17}, {x:13, y:2}, {x:6, y:24}];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    points[i].x = 1 + 23 * Math.random(); points[i].y = 1 + 23 * Math.random();
}
for (var i in points) textOutput("point: " + points[i].x.toFixed(3) + "," + points[i].y.toFixed(3) + "<BR>");
var size = 10;
var square = positionSquare(points, size);

// SHOW RESULT ON CANVAS
for (var i in points) {
    paintDot(canvas, points[i].x, points[i].y, 5, "red");
    paintLine(canvas, points[i].x, points[i].y, square[i].x, square[i].y, 1, "blue");
}
paintSquare(canvas, square, 1, "green");

function paintDot(canvas, x, y, size, color) {
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.arc(8 * x, 200 - 8 * y, size, 0, 6.2831853);
canvas.closePath();
canvas.fillStyle = color;
canvas.fill();
}
function paintLine(canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, width, color) {
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(8 * x1, 200 - 8 * y1);
canvas.lineTo(8 * x2, 200 - 8 * y2);
canvas.strokeStyle = color;
canvas.stroke();
}
function paintSquare(canvas, square, width, color) {
    canvas.rect(8 * square[0].x , 200 - 8 * square[0].y, 8 * size, 8 * size);
canvas.strokeStyle = color;
canvas.stroke();
}

// TEXT OUTPUT
function textOutput(t) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML += t;
}
```

```html
<BODY STYLE="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;">
<CANVAS ID="canvas" STYLE="width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; background-color: #F8F8F8;"></CANVAS>
<DIV ID="output" STYLE="width: 400px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;"></DIV>
</BODY>
```

Further improvements: I haven't yet taken into account what happens when a corner and a robot are in the same spot, but the overall position isn't optimal. Since the direction from the corner to the robot is undefined, it should probably be taken out of the equation temporarily.

Comment: Could you please explain how differential equations would apply to this particular problem? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @NeelayTrivedi It was just a hunch, based on the fact that I was comparing multiple effects of tiny movements to choose an optimal direction. I'm afraid I don't know enough about that kind of math to help you there. That's precisely why I went down a more practical path. Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?